# Changing background in html style, changes size too

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to change the backgroung using one way binding to change the source of the background. The problem is that, when I change the background, the size changes too and does not stay the same size.

html:

```
<div class= "col-md-12" id="buttonZone" style="position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;display: grid;min-height: 600px;background-size: 100% 100%;background-position: center;background: url('/../../assets/Images/generic/banner{{player.rank}}.png')">
```

I am doing this because I need the image to be under the buttons, but I don't want the `div` or the image to have `position: absolute`

Comment: Then why do you set position absolute if you dont want to do so? Please show us a full example of what you try to achieve thatbwe could trully help

Comment: if you want to retain your code and want to use 100% background size and do not care about image's quality being muddled, I suggest you use `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 0):

Since your background size is set 100% for both width and height, the change in appearance you're witnessing with the images are due to the fact that you're using images with different dimensions!

Try background-size 'cover' or 'contain' and see if it helps.

Alternatively, you can edit your images to have the same dimensions, but then you'll have to worry about small screens!